# SpringBoot Exported Jar fails to load Autowired

Tags: java, spring, maven, export

I'm currently working with an Spring Boot Application. This app has two Projects, one for common classes, and other with specifics.  Running in Eclipse works fine, but when I try to run the App as a Runnable JAR,  it fails.

This is my pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>BatchCare</groupId>
<artifactId>BatchCare</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>ar.com.tr.latam.care.InitBatch</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>               
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.simpleframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>simple-xml</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.1.0.7.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <!-- <version>1.3.2</version> -->
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
        <version>3.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jaxen</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxen</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>Library</groupId>
        <artifactId>Library</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </repository>

    <repository>
        <id>local-repo</id>
        <name>Local Project Repo</name>
        <url>file://${basedir}/lib/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
</repositories>
</project>
```

Library, is the project with common files.  I'd build it with mvn install, and then added the reference to the pom.xml

I've tried mvn: package ; mvn clean compile assembly:single; mvn spring-boot:repackage  . But everything I try does not work, when I run the .jar, it says that could not Autowire different classes.

The goal is to be able to run the project as a jar. 
Any help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you "open" the generated jar, do you find your `Library` jar ?

Comment: Remove the assembly plugin. The spring-boot plugin takes care of all that.

Comment: were you able to fix this problem?